# Thecus NAS read filename, create directory, move file to directory

Tags: unix, directory

I have my NAS downloading files. When the download is done, need to start a script that wil do the following:

- Read the filename
- Create a directory with the same name
- Move the file inside the directory

If possible
- move all just created directories to a different location, except for the existing directories.

Example:
Files and folders in the directory are

```
/downloaded1/ignored
/downloaded1/abc.doc
/downloaded1/def.doc
/downloaded1/ghi.doc
/downloaded1/jkl.doc
```

When the script is activated it should do the following:
create 4 directories

```
/downloaded1/abc/
/downloaded1/def/
/downloaded1/ghi/
/downloaded1/jkl/
```

Move the files inside the folder

```
/downloaded1/abc/abc.doc
/downloaded1/def/def.doc
/downloaded1/ghi/ghi.doc
/downloaded1/jkl/jkl.doc
```

If possible
Move the folders (including files) to:

```
/downloaded2/abc/
/downloaded2/def/
/downloaded2/ghi/
/downloaded2/jkl/
```

But the already exising folders (the ignored folder) should stay!!

Comment: Okay, now show us what you have done so far.

Comment: i tried with:
``for file in {}*.*; do
    dir=${file%%.*}
    mkdir -p "$dir"
    mv "$file" "$dir"
done``
But no succes. It says that its not valid.